# Asmack for facebook chat doesn't work with PrivacyListManager

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am working in an android application and I have integrated facebook chat into my android application successfully with aSmack. But when I login to the facebook chat with aSmack libary, my facebook status is available to every one in FB. I want to set a privacy list so that only my selected friends will be able to see me online in facebook.

But when I tried to set my privacy list with PrivacyListManager of aSmack libary  ,its always returns an error `feature-not-implemented(501)`. Is there any solution for this using aSmack?

Please look into my code :

```
  // Get the privacy manager for the current connection.  
      PrivacyListManager privacyManager = PrivacyListManager
        .getInstanceFor(connection);

       try {
       PrivacyList[] lists = privacyManager.getPrivacyLists();
       privacyManager.createPrivacyList(listName, privacyItems);
      } catch (XMPPException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

If its not possible with aSmack, please suggest me an another solution.

Answer (score 1):

That would indicate that the server doesn't support that feature.  Which is accurate when compared to their [chat developers page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).

It appears they don't have full XMPP support for the core specification and only support a couple of XEP's.

This isn't a Smack/aSmack problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any other method or library to implement my requirement.

Comment: Ask Facebook to implement the feature.